# Что могло послужить причиной ошибки SqlState == "23505" при добавлении записи

Tags: postgresql

Все мои таблицы представлены в программе объектами классов унаследованных от DbObject.
И к некотороым из них я программно добавлял записи по схеме

```
var newRecord = xTableDataModel.FillToEntity(); // get object as DbObject
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
   {
   AisDataManager.Active.xTable.Add(newRecord); 
    …
```

Однако, когда понадобилась добавить запись еще в одну таблицу, схема не сработала, выдав сообщение

```
catch (exception for Postgres)
   {
   if (ex.SqlState == "23505")
   throw new InvalidOperationException (@"Violation of the uniqueness of one of the fields", Ex);
   …
```

на строке

```
var ident = this.Context.Insert in the table(this.The name of the table this.Metadata.Identity.Information About The Property.Name, GetDbParams (item, this.Metadata.DbFieldsWithoutIdent));
```

Что могло послужить причиной?

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Answer (score 0):

Помог скрипт

```
select setval('parameters_id_seq', ((select max("Id") from parameter)))
```